# Numeric sort in CakePHP paginator

Tags: mysql, sorting, cakephp, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-2.x

I have the following code in CakePHP.

```
<th> <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('standard_id', 'Standard'); ?></th>
<th> <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?> </th>
<th> <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('title'); ?> </th>
```

My data for `standard_id` is like this:

- 3rd
- 4th
- 10th
- 11th
- ... etc.

My problem is `standard_id` is not sorted properly, it is considering it as a string. I want to apply a numeric sort.

Any Idea?

Comment: I guess your data is mix of Number and Character, so it will consider as string only . Can you tell which version of CakePHp you are using?

Comment: I am using cakephp-2.4.7

Comment: According to my knowledge the default Sorting gives the above result. In PHP, there is option to change the default sort behaviour for alphanumeric strings using natsort(), ie Natural sort. http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php  . Since CakePHP sorting applies to the MYSQL query, you can try another option . Please read how Natural Sort implemented for CakePHP and MYSQL . http://gobagel.blogspot.in/2010/10/cakephp-12-natural-alphanumeric-sorts.html

Comment: Ok. Thank you @KiranKrishnan :)

Comment: If worked, please post here !

Comment: You can safe yourself a lot of trouble by simply storing the numbers (additionally) without suffix.

Comment: @KiranKrishnan, yes i post it here, if it will work.

Comment: @ndm, i am not getting "storing the numbers (additionally)".

Comment: Either simply remove the suffix from the existing values (and add it on output), or add an additional column that holds just the number and sort by that column instead.

Comment: Hello, i have solved with "beforeFind" callback method. 
public function beforeFind($queryData) { 
          $queryData['order'][0] = array("CAST(column_name AS UNSIGNED)" => "ASC");
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your model:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['standard_id_numeric'] = sprintf('CAST(%s.standard_id as UNSIGNED)', $this->alias);
}
```

Now you should be able to sort by `standard_id_numeric`.

Alternatively, you can declare the virtual field as:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'standard_id_numeric' => 'CAST(Standard.standard_id as UNSIGNED)'
);
```

However, this will throw an error if you instantiate your model with an alias.

See

- Cookbook 2.x: Virtual fields: [Pagination and virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#pagination-and-virtual-fields).

Comment: It is also working. But, from both solutions which should be applicable?
i have other modules too like this one (same field standard_id_numeric) and i want to make it as common. so, i put this in AppModel but it is not working.

Comment: In CakePHP 2.x, using virtual fields is the right approach. While your solution might work for now, is rather hackish, and will surely break your app at some point. Regarding putting this code in your `AppModel`, it should work, provided the parent constructor is called. What error are you getting?

Comment: it is giving syntax error. i think i am doing something wrong. don't know about virtual field concept.
in my index file code is like this:
`<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Standard.standard', 'Standard'); ?></th>`
AppModel code is as follows:
`public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
$this->virtualFields['standard'] = sprintf('CAST(Standard.standard as UNSIGNED)', $this->alias);
}`

Comment: The syntax for `sprintf` is wrong. You have to include `%s`, which gets replaced with the contents of `$this->alias`. Also, the name of the virtual field must be different from those existing in the table. Check my edit.

Comment: Still not working for AppModel. it is giving syntax error in sql query.
However, decided to apply this solution for required individual model.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Query for natural sort in mysql is:
SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY CAST(column_name AS UNSIGNED) ASC;

Therefore, i used "beforeFind" callback method in model. The code is like below.

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    if(isset($queryData['sort'])){
        if($queryData['sort'] == "standard" && $queryData['direction']=="asc"){
            $queryData['order'][0] = array("CAST(Standard.standard AS UNSIGNED)" => "ASC");
        }elseif($queryData['sort'] == "standard" && $queryData['direction']=="desc"){
            $queryData['order'][0] = array("CAST(Standard.standard AS UNSIGNED)" => "DESC");
        }
    }

    return $queryData;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that doing so will make it impossible for MySQL to use indices, resulting in every single row to be examined, and thus slow down your query. I'd still recommend to store raw numbers or use an additional column for sorting instead.